# How to get two MapFragments in the same activity - Google Map Api

Tags: android, google-maps, mapfragment

I need to display two MapFragments with two different locations in an activity.
In my XML file I have two MapFragments called "map" and "map_two", and in java my code in onCreate is :

```
com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(map);
        mapCount = 1;
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment mapFragmentTwo = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(map_two);
        mapCount = 2;
        mapFragmentTwo.getMapAsync(this);
```

Then I override onMapReady :

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    if (mapCount == 1){
    mMap = googleMap;
    LatLng vannes = new LatLng(47.66, -2.75);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(vannes).title("Vannes"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(vannes));

    } else if (mapCount == 2){
        mMap = googleMap;
        LatLng bordeaux = new LatLng(44.833328, -0.56667);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(bordeaux).title("Bordeaux"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(bordeaux));

    } 
}
```

My issue is that the two maps show the same location, whereas I want to show two different locations. Do you see how to make it ?

Thank you,

Alex

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best way to do that, is create 2 different callbacks for each map:

```
public OnMapReadyCallback onMapReadyCallback1(){
        return new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                mMap = googleMap;
                LatLng vannes = new LatLng(47.66, -2.75);
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(vannes).title("Vannes"));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(vannes));
            }
        };
    }

    public OnMapReadyCallback onMapReadyCallback2(){
        return new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                mMap = googleMap;
                LatLng bordeaux = new LatLng(44.833328, -0.56667);
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(bordeaux).title("Bordeaux"));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(bordeaux));

            }
        };
    }
```

After add these 2 methods in your `Activity`, you have to set them in your Maps:

```
com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(map);
        mapCount = 1;
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(onMapReadyCallback1());
        com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment mapFragmentTwo = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(map_two);
        mapCount = 2;
        mapFragmentTwo.getMapAsync(onMapReadyCallback2());
```

Comment: this should be considered the best answer imo